# Detecting if user has not done any activity on the web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show user a popup if he has been there on a web page without doing any mouse clicks / keyboard press / mouse scrolling

Is there any way I can track this using javascript?

Comment: For what reason you want to detect, that's important. You can manage session or you can do it with even Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

```
var timeout = false;
function checkActivity() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () { alert('inactive'); }, AmountOfTime);
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', checkActivity);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', checkActivity);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', checkActivity);
checkActivity();
```

What this does is run a function after `AmountOfTime` milliseconds.  It is reset on any user activity on the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [Keyboard Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events) and [Mouse Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) in JavaScript.

You can have a timer counting down to when the user should be shown that message, and reset the timer whenever you get an eligible event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (library)[https://github.com/mikesherov/jquery-idletimer] to detect, if the user is idle.

Example:

```
$(document).on('idle.idleTimer', function() {
    //do something on idle;
    });
$(document).on('active.idleTimer', function() {
    //so something on activity;
    });
$(document).idleTimer(1000, {
    startImmediately: false,
    idle: true,
    enabled: true,
    events: 'keydown' //there are more events in the docs;
});
```